# Return row or column from a 2D array

Tags: c++, c++11, matrix

I have a 2D array class that is actually mapped to a 1D vector. For example, to obtain an element at a particular position, the code is as follows:

```
template <typename T>
T mat <T>::at(const size_t &row, const size_t &col) const
{
  return m_values[row*ncol() + col];
}
```

Here's the relevant section of the class in-context:

```
template <typename T>
class mat
{
private:
  std::vector <T> m_values;
  size_t m_nrow, m_ncol;
public:
  mat();

  size_t ncol() const{ return m_ncol; };
  size_t nrow() const{ return m_nrow; };

  T at(const size_t &row, const size_t &col) const;
  std::vector <T> row(const size_t &row) const;
  std::vector <T> col(const size_t &col) const;
};
```

`m_nrow` and `m_ncol` contain the number of rows and columns of the 2D array, respectively, while `m_values` contains the values of the array. They're assigned in another (long) constructor.

I now need to be able to return an entire row or column. Here's how that's currently implemented:

```
template <typename T>
std::vector <T> mat <T>::row(const size_t &row) const
{
  std::vector <T> tmp;
  for(size_t j=0; j < ncol(); j++)
  {
    tmp.push_back(at(row, j));
  }
  return tmp;
}

template <typename T>
std::vector <T> mat <T>::col(const size_t &col) const
{
  std::vector <T> tmp;
  for(size_t i=0; i < nrow(); i++)
  {
    tmp.push_back(at(i, col));
  }
  return tmp;
}
```

These implementations are easy to reason about but not particularly efficient: there's the pushing back to a temporary vector and the repeated calculation of `row*ncol()` in `at()`. Is there a more idiomatic way of doing this in C++11?

Comment: Please post complete code. What is `m_values`? What is `mat`? What are `ncol()`and `nrow()`? These are very relevant. Stub code is off-topic here.

Comment: What do you expect to do with a row (or column). If the only thing is check size and accesses elements then a simple wrapper class that accesses the parent seems more appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Lack of modifiability**

Your `at()`, `row()` and `col()` return copies. This means that once you construct your `mat`, it's permanently const. Also, for some `T`s, this makes these functions unnecessarily expensive.

Prefer instead for `at()` to return a reference:

```
T& at(size_t row, size_t col);
T const& at(size_t row, size_t col) const;
```

Although, typically with the standard library, the `at()` member functions also do range checking. So consider some other non-throwing indexing mechanism (maybe `operator()`) and have `at()` defer to that one while doing bounds checking. Note that you don't need to pass the `size_t`s by reference-to-const, value is fine.

Now, for the other two, prefer instead:

```
std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<T>>       row(size_t );
std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<const T>> row(size_t ) const;
std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<T>>       col(size_t );
std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<const T>> col(size_t ) const;
```

`reference_wrapper<T>` since you can't have `vector<T&>`.

**Constructing those rows/cols**

Since you're storing everything in row order, returning a row can just use the iterator-pair constructor of `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<T>> row(size_t r)
{
    auto start = m_values.begin() + r * ncol();
    return {start, start + ncol()};
}
```

Returning a column is much more annoying, but you definitely want to use `reserve()` to avoid any extra allocations:

```
std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<T>> col(size_t c)
{
    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<T>> result;
    result.reserve(nrows());
    for (size_t r = 0; r < nrows(); ++r) {
        result.push_back((*this)(r, c));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Where I'm assuming `operator()` is the non-throwing version of `at`.

Comment: I certainly agree with adding bounds checking to the `at()` function. Can you explain why I shouldn't pass the `size_t`s by reference-to-const? I am using `const` in that situation to signal that the `size_t`s should not be modified in the body of the function. I also agree that I should `reserve()` the size of the vector.

Comment: @ruser45381 It might actually be more expensive to pass small types by reference than by copy. You can/should keep it `const` to indicate that it will not be changed, but removing the reference part is a good idea.

Comment: That's good to know.

Comment: @user2296177: Your argument for that? Just becuase it is smaller does not mean it is cheaper. Below a certain point a register is a register is a register no matter what the size.

Comment: @LokiAstari I used this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27260446/2296177. You seem to be correct in that it may not actually matter.

Comment: @user2296177: It's worse than "doesn't actually matter": The compiler cannot assume that the references don't alias each other and/or something in the vector / potentially modified by any of the functions you call.